# Automatic install of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, automation

Is there a batch script (or even something like ninite) that can automatically download and install visual studio express?

Comment: Have a look at [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) it is somewhat like apt-get and has packages built for almost all version of visual studio: http://chocolatey.org/packages/VisualStudio2012WDX

Comment: @nemesv this looks like exactly what I wanted, if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely have a look on [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/):

> Chocolatey NuGet is a Machine Package Manager, somewhat like apt-get,
>   but built with Windows in mind.

From the [chocolatey wiki](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki)

> For those unfamiliar with apt/debian, think about chocolatey as a global silent installer for applications and tools. It can also do configuration tasks and anything that you can do with PowerShell.

So it can download and install any tool if somebody creates a chocolatey package for it. Lucikly for [almost any version of visual studio](http://chocolatey.org/packages?q=visual%20studio) there is package.

For example here is link to [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop 11.0](http://chocolatey.org/packages/VisualStudio2012WDX) package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some prep work for it to work unattended.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx